# how to say "It does not make any difference"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I want to know what is the correct(most common) way to say

> It doesn't make any difference"

Is it something like `es macht keinen Unterschied` or is there a better way to say this.

Comment: Can you provide more context? There are a lot of ways to say that.

Comment: for example if someone says "why don't you do so and so?" and you answer it doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Es macht keinen Unterschied.

is a very good translation. Colloquially, you could also say

> Es kommt auf dasselbe raus.
>
> Es kommt aufs Gleiche raus.
>
> Es ist gehüpft wie gesprungen (or some dialectal variant).

Some more good suggestions from the comments:

> Es spielt keine Rolle (thanks @Chris)
>
> Es ist gleich/egal. (thanks @karoshi)

Comment: which is most commonly used?

Comment: Und: Es spielt keine Rolle

Comment: Also colloquially: Das ist Jacke wie Hose.

Comment: Also: "es ist gleich", "es ist egal".

Comment: @mosaad most common in my surrounding: "es/das macht keinen Unterschied" and "das kommt auf's gleiche raus" (equally common)